# Putting classes in different folders but calling them under the same name space?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework in my web application project and there are going to be a LOT of tables in the proejct cauing a lot of class files having to be made. I want to orginize the class files into folders to make it easier to find them and modify if needed. Can I orginize the files in different folders but have them all have the same "namespace" name in the class and have no problems calling the files? I.E. Some files are under the folders Project.DAL.Tables1 others are under Project.DAL.Tables2 but in each class file I give them all the namespace Project.DAL and then in .aspx files just call using Project.DAL

I have done some experimentation and so far I am not seeing any issues but being a Jr. Dev I just want to make sure I should not experiance any unforseen issues in the feature.

Comment: Are these classes that you write by yourself, or are they generated by Entity?

Comment: I am using code first and the classes are hand written by me.

Comment: you will not run into any issues. I have tested it myself and it is fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, my testings showed no issues but I just wanted to make sure no one else knew of any other problems.

Comment: If your classes are hand written you can go on, you won't have any problems with that. (you can even have the same namespace in different projects and it will still work)

Comment: @ppetrov As an example, at least three different assemblies (`mscorlib.dll`, `System.dll`, and `System.Core.dll`) contribute to the namespace `System`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that's what I was thinking about, but it's good to mention the example ;)

Comment: Please select the correct answer.  Looks like saravanan's in my experience.

Comment: @kirsteng and how would I do that? There are only comments on my question there are no "answers".

Comment: message @saravanan  by putting an @ in front of his name and ask him to  add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues with changing the namespace given to a .cs file